# How to delete an array of pointers to generic type objects

Tags: c++

My class has a generic array of pointers member named `A`:

```
T** A
```

Currently, i delete the array in the destructor in the following way:

```
~MyQuickInitArray(){
    delete [] A;
};
```

Will this cause a memory leak? if so, should i iterate through the array and call `delete` on each object?

On a side note -  Do I need to call `delete [] B` if `B` is an array of integers or does the destructor handles it already?

**EDIT:**

This is how the allocation occurs:

```
MyQuickInitArray(int size)
{
    if(size <= 0)
    {
        throw new std::exception;
    }

    _size = size;
    _counter = 0;
    A = new T*[size];
    B = new int[size];
    C = new int[size];
}
    MyQuickInitArray(const MyQuickInitArray& myQuickInitArray)
    {
        _size = myQuickInitArray._size;
        _counter = myQuickInitArray._counter;
        A = new T*[_size];

        for(int i = 0; i<_size ;i++)
        {
            if(myQuickInitArray.A[i] != NULL)
            {
                A[i] = new T(*myQuickInitArray.A[i]);
            }
        }

        B = myQuickInitArray.B;
        C = myQuickInitArray.C;
    }
```

Comment: Unless you show allocation code how can one say if deallocation code is correct or not?

Comment: @user1929959 A is not a pointer to an array of pointers

Comment: @AlokSave please view my edit

Comment: whoa, why this `throw new std::exception;`?? Throw by value catch by reference(possibly const).

Comment: @AlokSave can you elaborate what is wrong with this?

Comment: Because you dynamically allocate a object being thrown, there can be multiple things that can go wrong with that. Do a little bit of research it should help you understand better. If you still have doubts ask a specific question here. In short the rule as i stated it throw by value catch by reference(possibly const).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will this cause a memory leak?

You can surely count on it if `A` is an array of pointers. You need loop through the array and delete the pointers yourself.

```
~MyQuickInitArray {
    for (int i =_size; i--;) {
        delete A[i];
    }
    delete [] A;
}
```

> Do I need to call `delete [] B` if `B` is an array of integers or does the destructor handle it?

Yes, always delete that which is allocated with `new`. You can do this inside your class's destructor.

Comment: You have used `delete` in your program. This is incorrect. You should use an appropriate smart pointer.

Comment: Firstly it's not incorrect and secondly by your wording it follows that the OP deserves a downvote as well.

Answer (score 1):

> Will this cause a memory leak?

Yes, calling `delete[]` on the array of pointers without deleting items pointed to by individual elements will cause a memory leak, because "built-in" pointers of C++ do not have ownership semantic. Consider using "smart" pointers, e.g. `unique_ptr<T>` instead of "plain" ones to avoid calling destructors in a loop.

> Do I need to call delete [] B if B is an array of integers

You need to call `delete[]` on everything that you allocated with `new[]`, regardless of the element type of the array.

Comment: You should place a bit more emphasis on the use of `unique_ptr`.